# Unknown component from PSU. Transformer or inductor?

Tags: identification, coil

What is this component I salvaged from an ATX PSU? It looks like most inductors, toroidal in shape, however, rather than just one wire wrapped around the core forming a winding there are five.

I thought it was simply an economic inductor of some sorts but when I noticed one wire (winding) was of a different gauge enamel coated copper wire, I remembered a Great Scotts video where I saw a large transformer in a toroidal shape.

I've included an image of this transformer. If you happen to have any information (datasheet/resources) I could go to to learn more about this questionable-looking component that would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With no further info about the original functionality of the power supply and no info from which what part of the circuit the inductor was removed, it most likely is the common output filter for the output voltages.

In the [Wikipedia article on computer power supplies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)) it would be the inductor between rectifying diodes and output capacitors through which multiple output voltages pass.

Comment: hi thanks for your response. do you think you could give me a quote around where in the wiki article they speak of this? they dont talk mention the word "inductor" in the wiki article, so ill just search the page for it

Comment: The article does not talk about it, just look at the simplified circuit diagrams.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is an inductor on a SMPS. The overwinds are a way of getting different voltages with reasonable cross regulation.